# how to pause/resume LiquidSlider animations

Tags: jquery

How can I pause/resume transition to next slide when mouse is over/out of the current slide in LiquidSlider http://liquidslider.com?

Answer (score 0):

http://liquidslider.com/documentation/

> pauseOnHover: true
>
> This pauses the slider when someone hovers over it. Note that it doesn't work on crosslinks.

So when you instantiate the slider, set `pauseOnHover: true`

```
$('#mySlider').liquidSlider({ pauseOnHover: true });
```

Comment: this option is for pausing the auto-slide feature not the transition itself. Actually, I want to pause the animation during transition

Comment: @user1723583 I'd be very surprised if there's any way to do that. It's very much a non-standard feature

Comment: Yes, but that script is specifically designed to support pausing during the transition. LiquidSlider is not, and making it support that kind of behaviour would be a **huge** job, in all likelihood

Answer (score 0):

There is a property for `liquid slider` to `pause/resume` on `mouse hover`.

Set this option in the function

```
pauseOnHover: true
```

For example

```
$('#slider').liquidSlider({ pauseOnHover: true });
```

**Reference - http://liquidslider.com/documentation/#autoslide-options**

Comment: Wow, both posted at the same **second**. Who had the stopwatch out for the milliseconds?

Comment: this option is for pausing the auto-slide feature not the transition itself. Actually, I want to pause the animation during transition